# jq - select contains array or/and

Tags: json, jq

Currently this works:

```
jq -r '.[] | select(.hosts | contains('$array')).hostName')
```

If `array = ["darwin","intel"]`it returns objects containing both darwin "and" intel.
How can I make it return objects containing darwin "and/or" intel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your jq has `any/2`, I'd recommend using the following definition of `intersectq/2`:

```
def intersectq(a;b): any(a[]; . as $x | any( b[]; . == $x) );
```

The filter to use is then simply:

```
.[] | select( intersectq(.hosts; $array)) | .hostName
```

as in:

```
jq --argjson array '["darwin","intel"]' -r -f program.jq hosts.json
```